# Can you enable variable highlighting with Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

I'm using version 3.3.2, I know that regular Eclipse for Java does variable highlighting.
Notepad++ does it regardless of what language you're using (if you select any text, it highlights similar text)

I know it's not critically important, and a back/forward incremental search is an adequate workaround, but it would be nice to have.

**Update** Looks like I had PDT 1.03, (current version is 2.0), I have Eclipse 3.2.2. Needed to look in "Help -> Software Updates -> Manage Configuration", not just "Help -> About".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download new PDT 2.0 All-in-one together with Eclipse 3.4 - this feature as "mark occurences" is here an there is some new features. I use it now and found it stable.

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I believe 'mark occurrences' is the option which is the closest of what you call 'syntax highlighting'

But [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) (PDT) had not that feature in 2007, according to [this discussion](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.php/msg01188.html).

However [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166178) says PDT1.1 has now the ability to mark occurrences.

Full description in this [pdf document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c2/MarkOccurrences_(Dev2QA).pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question in poorly worded. Syntax highlighting, and highlighting all similar strings are very different.

Comment: Thanks. I even double-checked the (content) of my question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about PDT but I would suggest to try [PHPEclipse](http://phpeclipse.net/) plugin instead, which is much more powerful. It gives you pretty much everything that Eclipse provides for java - marking occurrences, Ctrl-click navigation, code completion, etc.

Comment: I've already got ctrl-click and code-completion. What do you mean by marking occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to highlight the word then right click -> refactor -> rename OR just Alt-Shift-R

This highlights all occurrences of the variable.

Esc key to stop highlighting.

Just be sure you don't accidentally rename it (easy enough to undo if you do).